# How to get columns in Export CSVs in ss_report Silverstripe?

Tags: php, csv, silverstripe

```
class Report1 extends SS_Report
{

public function columns()
    {
        $fields = array(

            'Date' => 'Date',
            'Method' => 'Method',
            'Number'   => ' No(NEW)',

        );

        return $fields;
    }
}
```

I needs to export these columns to csv. And i already define a getExportFields() in particular model. If i going to download csv here output gives defined feilds in getExportFields(). So can anyone help to solve this

Comment: Can you please clarify the problem? Is it that the report is not using the columns you've defined when exporting to CSV, or that the `getExportFields()` in your model isn't being used?

Comment: solved the problem using this $gridField->getConfig()->addComponent(new GridFieldExportButton("after", ["Date", "Method","Amount", "Reference"]));